# How do I click enter when a "save-as" window is open with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to save [this file](https://www.shs-conferences.org/articles/shsconf/pdf/2019/06/shsconf_m3e22019_03006.pdf) using Selenium. I'm able to click "save-as" with the following code:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path = chrome_driver_path)
driver.get('https://www.shs-conferences.org/articles/shsconf/pdf/2019/06/shsconf_m3e22019_03006.pdf')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plugin"]')).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

However, I cannot get python to press the "save" bottom in the pop-up window. I have tried:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Save')]").click()
```

and

```py
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(u'\ue007').perform()
```

Anyone know how to click the "save" bottom?

Comment: There are better ways to download pdf file than using selenium to do this. see answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844729/download-pdf-using-urllib

Comment: @Sureshmani that isn't what the user asked. If you're going to offer an alternative method, you should also outline how to do it in Selenium, and explain why it's not a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the download of files with Selenium + Python bindings in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654358/how-to-control-the-download-of-files-with-selenium-python-bindings-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## UPDATE

While as said above by @Glazbee `selenium` cannot access OS dialog there is a work-around with `pyautogui`. Try the following if you do not want to set a default download folder in your `chrome_options` of your `webdriver`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyautogui
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path = chrome_driver_path)
driver.get('https://www.shs-conferences.org/articles/shsconf/pdf/2019/06/shsconf_m3e22019_03006.pdf')

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plugin"]')).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('s').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Comment: It does not work - nothing happens when the code is executed

Comment: @Modvinden is that a pop-up to save a file?

Comment: This won't work. Chrome doesn't render the save dialogue to the page, it is instead passed from native code. As Selenium doesn't have access to the native binaries - Just the Javascript rendered to a page - It cannot access a save dialogue.

Comment: @Glazbee you're right I didn't get what he was trying to do before, I thought he just needed to press `enter`. There is a work around though.

Comment: Will your updated solution work on a headless browser? I know it was on the roadmap, but I didn't think it was released just yet

Comment: @Glazbee hmm that's a good observation though I cannot reproduce while when running the above headless does not find the `xpath` element provided.

Comment: pyautogui.press('enter') - working fine. thanks - @KostasCharitidis

Answer (score 5):

you can use the keyboard module in combination with selenium

```
import keyboard, time

keyboard.press(['ctrl', 's'])
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('enter')
```

This will let you save the file.

Comment: this was really helpul. Thanks, i hope it works in headless mode

Comment: Haven't tested in headless mode but it works well with UI. I am using `keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+s')` instead as suggested [here](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This answer has been reported to be outdated. I am not in a position to test this, please look into using solutions from other answers.

The reason this isn't working for you is that the save dialogue used by Chrome is not rendered as a web page. It's native code.

To get around this, you can use the `selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options` module. You will need to set a default file directory, otherwise, a prompt will appear. You can use a script like the following; [You can find more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40656336/10595994). You can also find information on [why experimental options are used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43277321/10595994)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the pop-up still appears.

Comment: @AbhishekRai apologies for the delay in response. I no longer work with Selenium, but as of Oct 2019, this was working (Unfortunately I do not have the version numbers).