# Python and Selenium headless - download file and option for "save as"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can't seem to get the last part of my python with selenium to work. The goal is to download a file from a web portal (excel file). I'm using chrome as the webdriver and I'm able to login and navigate through the site and even click on the button to trigger the download. However, manually, if you click on the button, you get the "save as" screen. How do you enter a path and file name to complete the download in the script? thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I click enter when a "save-as" window is open with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432057/how-do-i-click-enter-when-a-save-as-window-is-open-with-selenium)

Comment: @BuddyBobIII, thanks for the answer. It's weird, it looks like clicking on the link doesnt trigger anything. my code is driver.find_element_by_id("lbNonPharmacy").click(). The code is able to find the item since I also use a similar line of code to get the file name from the element and it's working. but click() doesnt open anything...