# Webscraping site that downloads a file in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a table from a website.
I obviously get the XPATH of the table to use in the Selenium driver - but the website already produces a file which we can download of the same table.
I click on an icon and it opens a SAVE AS dialog box.

Using selenium, how can I just download this file? How do I just save it directly?

Answer (score 0):

According to older posts, some degree of input is emulated. (using `pyautogui`). Probably just an enter key on keyboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58432097/19042045